# require a php file located in domain into a subdomain

Tags: php, subdomain, require

So I  am working on a site that will require me to include a file into a subdomain.

This is the first time I have had an issue trying to require a file.
So I have a php file located in

```
domain.com/folder/myfile.php
```

I am trying to include the file from `blog.subdomain.com`.
Like i always do, i used the code below.

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require $root.'/folder/myfile.php';
```

But i get all kinds of errors. This is the first time I have tried including a file into a subdomai so I have never exprienced this before.

Comment: All kinds of errors? What are the errors?

Comment: Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home2/mysitename/public_html/folder/myfile.php' (include_path='.:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear') in

Comment: looks like myfile.php has a dependency relative to that path that throws a fatal error when required to a different location.. check the included file first.

Answer (score 0):

> 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' refers to the document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

As described in:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

To get the current site domain from PHP, use SERVER_NAME instead:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

**Edit:**

So if your current page is on a subdomain, you can extract the main domain from it:

```
// $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'blog.domain.com'
// Extract "domain.com"
substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '.') + 1);
```

Comment: Hey, that prints out the subdomain. But I am trying to access a file in the main domain.

Comment: You can extract the "main" domain the subdomain. `substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '.') + 1)`

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think this answers my questions. How do I require the file into the subdomain.

Comment: As you said you want to include a file located at `domain.com/folder/myfile.php`. So I am answering you the way to get the main domain from a page under subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

You want to access `myfile.php` in **domain.com** while you're building code in **blog.subdomain.com**. 
I think there's no solution if your file (`myfile.php`) is a php class file but if it's an usual php file (like printing/echoing some texts) you can get it with **CURL** technique.

> I believe that you are not in the subdomain actually (It's more like
>   *x.com* and *y.com*).

If you want to access `myfile.php` in ***domain*.com** from **blog.*domain*.com**, that will be a bit tricky.
I have done a little modification with your code:

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$root = str_ireplace('blog.', '', $root); // this will remove "blog."
require $root.'/folder/myfile.php';
```

This code works for me.